# The best approach to store list in Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to keep a list with the ID of the users who liked the specific object. To achieve that I created an array where I'm trying to keep that list.

[image]

I also want to display how many users like that object.

In mapper:

```
likes = getLikedListSize(it["userLikedOfferList"].toString())
```

then

```
private fun getLikedListSize(userList: String): String {
        return userList.length.toString()
}
```

The problem is that function returns random numbers. For example in the array are two items, function return "8" etc.

What is a better approach to store list and get the size of it in Firestore?

Comment: Why are you converting `userLikedOfferList` (an array) to a string to determine it's length? Pass in the array itself to `getLikedListSize()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the following method call:

```
getLikedListSize(it["userLikedOfferList"].toString())
```

It means that you are trying to pass to the `getLikedListSize()` method, the String representation of the array object. This representation is nothing else but the address of the object in the memory. This address it's a String that consists of 8 characters. That's the reason why, when you call `.length` you return the length of that String and not the actual length of the array. To solve this, simply pass the array, without converting it to a String:

```
getLikedListSize(it["userLikedOfferList"])
```

And change the method like this:

```
private fun getLikedListSize(userList: Array<String>): Int {
    return userList.length
}
```

Now, when calling this method, you'll always get the number of elements that exist in the `userLikedOfferList` array.